# C11, 6.6.10: IB: other forms of constant expressions: additional conformance documentation is needed

Tags: c, constants, usability, constant-expression, implementation-defined-behavior

Why it (seems that it) is a general practice for C compiler vendors to not provide to the end users an additional conformance documentation about implementation-defined behavior regarding «other forms of constant expressions» (C11, 6.6.10)?

C11, 6.6.10:

> An implementation may accept other forms of constant expressions.

This fact leads to the following reactions / feedback (taken from different sources):

SO user M.M:

> The compiler vendor should publish conformance documentation listing which expressions it accepts as constants, although I couldn't find
> that documentation for MSVC. (leave a comment if you can!)

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62161678/9881330

SO user Keith Thompson:

> Admittedly the standard doesn't seem to require such documentation (which I find a little surprising).

Source: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66618 (2015-07-01 00:48:48 UTC)

Since the `6.6.10` is related to the implementation-defined behavior, and since «each implementation shall include documentation describing its characteristics and behavior» (C++ standard, section 1.9), why it is not a general practice in case of `6.6.10`? If someone here represents any (industrial) C compiler vendor then please provide the reason / comment the situation.

P.S. The origin of the question is the possible portability issues related to the «other forms of constant expressions». It will be much time-saving if the end users know exactly which «other forms of constant expressions» are «accepted by the implementation» *before* writing the code (and not after, being surprised by the portability issues).

UPD. Note on «When making use of implementation-defined behavior, I would assume portability issues until proven otherwise». If a software product is planned to be portable between N compilers and all the N compilers support the same IB-related language feature, which is useful while writing the code, but considered implementation-defined behavior, then why not use it? The only question is that we need to know *in advance* that this IB-related language feature is supported between all the N compilers. (Yes, we can empirically / experimentally find it, but in case of many IB-related language features it will be probably time-consuming. It is better to have an official statement from the compiler vendor that this IB-related language feature is supported / not supported.)

UPD: About "the standard doesn't seem to require such documentation": C11, 4. Conformance:

> An implementation **shall be accompanied by a document** that defines all implementation-defined and locale-specific characteristics and **all extensions**.

UPD:  I see the current state of affairs as follows: the C standard permits to "accept other forms of constant expressions". And gcc, clang, and icc do support other forms of constant expressions ([demo](https://godbolt.org/z/WK6P783oo)). However, the C standard is *silent* about whether such other forms of constant expressions are required to be accepted *consistently* across multiple usages (see the demo).

Comment: When making use of implementation-defined behavior, I would assume portability issues until proven otherwise.

Comment: Since MSVC compilers do not conform to C standards, you cannot expect them to conform to that clause either. But MS does provide extensive documentation.

Comment: Since you seem to be quoting answers or comments on Stack Overflow, [edit] the question to include links to those sources.

Comment: Someone apparently found an impl. defined constant expression in clang here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30158413/gcc-doesnt-support-simple-integer-constant-expression/30158502. Look in the clang manual, does it mention it?

Comment: One possible explanation is obvious: the standards committee aren't your customers, and actual customers don't care about having such a document.  So why spend time and money writing it if it won't improve sales / adoption of your compiler?